# Check if the dispatch vuex is done

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, dispatch

Hi I have this create and update zone function. After the API call success. I will callback again the dispatch on vuex store. Then Go back to main zone page. 
The problem is it will took around 5 secs to get the list the results of dispatch. Making my list not updated.

How to know if the dispatch is done before going back to the page?

```
loadZones(){
     this.$store.dispatch('getZones');
},

createOrUpdateZone(zone, region_checkbox, callback){
     this.$http.post(process.env.API_URL +'/api/.....)
      .then(res=> {
             if(res.data.success == true){
               this.loadZones();
               this.$router.push('/zone');
            } else{
               this.has_error = true;
     })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Vuex actions always return `Promise`, just add `return` when you create request in your `getZones` action to chain your ajax request promise with returned by action, then you can do something like this:

```
//... in actions, example
getZones(context) {
   return some_http_request()
}


//...
loadZones(){
    return this.$store.dispatch('getZones');
},

createOrUpdateZone(zone, region_checkbox, callback){
 this.$http.post(process.env.API_URL +'/api/.....)
  .then(res=> {
         if(res.data.success == true){
           // next "then" will be invoked when this request will be done
           return this.loadZones();
         }
         else throw new Error();
  })
  .then(() => {
      this.$router.push('/zone');
  })
  .catch(() => this.has_error = true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use async await.

When you make loadZones async function, in it you can use await on the dispatch getZones. But remember that the getZones action should return a promise. I believe that it already returning a promise, so you just have to add async await.

```
async loadZones(){
     await this.$store.dispatch('getZones');
},

createOrUpdateZone(zone, region_checkbox, callback){
     this.$http.post(process.env.API_URL +'/api/.....)
      .then(res=> {
             if(res.data.success == true){
               this.loadZones();
               this.$router.push('/zone');
            } else{
               this.has_error = true;
     })
}
```